# Calculating integral with antithetic variables

Tags: integration, markov-chains, monte-carlo, simulation

Use simulation with antithetic variables and find

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^\infty \sin(x+y)e^{-x^2+4x-y} \, dx \, dy.$$

so, my question and doubt is how struggle with the infinite limit ?

It is easy to me this problem $\int_0^1 e^x \, dx$ or similar,  but do not know how the previous.

Help me please.

Comment: It is not a mathematics problem --- [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) is a better place to ask.